# CentOS 5.5 - passing parameters from grub to the user space

Tags: linux, centos, boot, grub

I need to add an additional title to my grub.conf file and after OS boot I need start different services depends on it

What the better way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use runlevel 4 (normally unused) and pass `4` on the kernel command line to boot into it.

Comment: But all services are depends on runlevel it may be a risky and it will give me only two options. Is it possible to pass a string from the grub? Maybe to use some unused kernel parameter or something like that?

Comment: You can pass whatever you like and parse it out of `/proc/cmdline` after, but that is a lot more work.

Comment: Does kernel will ignore any unknown parameters?